# Von Neumann and Hausdorff continuous dimensions are related?

Tags: lattice-orders, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, noncommutative-geometry

Von Neumann in his book *Continuous Geometry* introduced (in a suitable lattice)  a dimension function that  has a continuous range. The definition of a dimension function is  axiomatic: see [Continuous geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_geometry) on  Wikipedia. It can take non-integer values; for example, the entire interval $[0,1]$ can be the range of a dimension function.

Also the [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension)  has a continuous range and is defined on the lattice of the subsets of a metric space. Is there any relation between these two concepts of dimension?

Comment: I can say "there is no known relation".  But to say "there is no relation" is beyond my pay grade.

Comment: @GEdgar I found [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0102209.pdf), but it's too hard for me.